# Launch openvpn SERVER (not client) on startup with no password prompts

Tags: networking, server, password, vpn, openvpn

I currently have an openvpn server setup on my desktop so that I can use it while traveling. Everything works and I can connect to it from my laptop from different networks.

If my house loses power I've set my computer to automatically restart. After it does that, I need it to launch the openvpn server without asking for a password like it currently does so that I can enter my password at the ubuntu login screen and continue using my computer remotely.

This seems like it should be a standard thing to discuss, but I haven't been able to find anything on it. I followed the guide [here](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#configuring-openvpn-to-run-automatically-on-system-startup) to setup openvpn. And I have only been able to find information online about using `auth-user-pass` on the client-side to automatically connect to a server. The same option can't be used on the server-side.

Is what I'm asking for even possible? Or is this disabled for some security reasons? If it's possible, how can I pull it off?

Info: I am using Ubuntu 20, and installed openvpn with `sudo apt install openvpn`

Comment: Please add the following information [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1447061/edit): the version of Ubuntu you are using, and how you installed openvpn. It should be installed as a service, which should start when the computer boots. You may have installed it incorrectly. The best way to install is to install from the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Thanks! I could check to see if the process is running on startup, it probably is. But just having openvpn process running doesn't mean that the particular server I have setup will be running, correct? That would still need to be launched in some way, and it will ask me for a password, I believe

Comment: I installed openvpn server using this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04 I don't have to do anything to start the server. It starts when the machine boots

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you!! That is a very useful guide. The key step seems to be using the `nopass` option in `./easyrsa gen-req server nopass` so that a password is not required to launch the server. There is just one problem that I have to get past the Ubuntu login screen before the server is launched. So it doesn't fully solve the problem of using my computer remotely if the power goes out. Any ideas how to solve that last problem?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Please mention the `nopass` option  and that link to that tutorial in an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: To get past the login screen you need to set the computer to autologin. How you do that depends on what flavor of Ubuntu you are using. There are many questions on this site about that already.

Comment: Just for completeness, a quick search for Ubuntu auto login yields [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @OrganicMarble for pointing out [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-a-certificate-authority-ca-on-ubuntu-20-04) from Digital Ocean.

The key step seems to be using the `nopass` option in `./easyrsa gen-req server nopass` so that a password is not required to launch the server.